# docker buildx build automatically pulls base image

Tags: docker, caching, buildx

I recently updated a Docker workflow to start using `buildx`.
I quickly noticed that the build of the Dockerfile was often restarting from scratch, even if from the last build I only added a layer "at the end".
Upon further inspection, It seems like the build is always trying to pull the base images (e.g. `FROM ubuntu:22.04`) and so, this results in invalidating the whole cache.

Before moving to `buildx` I was able to control this behavior by passing (or not) the `--pull` argument, and by looking at the new documentation this argument is still supported.
Then why am I seeing this behavior?

At a high level, this is what I'm doing.

```
docker buildx create --name my-builder

docker build \
    --builder my-builder \
    --platform=linux/amd64,linux/arm64
    --push
    --tag my-tag \
    --file path/to/Dockerfile \
    .
```

Thank you